# Point typescript to be more specific about an error

Tags: typescript

### TL;DR - I want to find a way to "simplify" an error when I'm in an outer scope.

### [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcBKFgFd0IAq40AvFAN5QAeAXFArgLYBGGUAvgFCiSyKoMABTjo4TAM5RyVOPUat23XtHjI06aVAAUYUeIn01g9CLGSAlNIB8-dRmx4CxSFy4B6AFSeuUT1BdoAHJtWU4jAQ0zAytSWyo6KAlgdABLBABzAG5OIKhUqQQAe2AoOAkJVIyEOBY0KGAihpIoIOMNIIA6Xyhe3oBhOBQUJKqap2h0HHwEZsgpIIT6ZLTMnI48gVb2h2nnEk2p-IQAYyKmPWBUuohuvvuAgAtoFSkigDNW6kPodLOLuBXG5QNjAADuEAgs2AzwkLxIEjuD3ugVaK3SGTyBQYJTKFTGtXqjTmwQUbHQXW0ACYAMxUqkWXyedxcM4IZJQAAyAHkAHIAcQA+gBRTCYbmYCL2TTkUJlTixeI9KZOWZLKAAIgArBrOFxuB5vEyAi0gujMljCrjypVqoSXk0VK0yRhKbT6YzeukwLhgJ1gBJqNoAIwAGigVIAHBZ6IRnlAINRICdgBAkCSoP8IFJ3uhzlAwHnIOhQF88mDHqkTo98lIkBATihRGmoM8jkVoaadlg9kQDkyWWyOQBlACSAFkhJzRwAxUfCgAiIrFEq0crg4TsJmililJkcM1RcUoyt7lBo9A1wd13G4QA)

---

Given the following code:

```js
type HandlerReturnType = { x: number }
type HandlerParams = { a: number }
type Handler = (params: HandlerParams) => HandlerReturnType

const handler: Handler = ({ a }) => ({ x: a })
```

Everything seems to work fine.

Until it's not.

When getting an error, the error that I'm getting from typescript is a bit out of scope:

```js
const handler: Handler = ({ a }) => {
  return { x: "string" }
}

// Type '({ a }: HandlerParams) => { x: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Handler'.
//  Call signature return types '{ x: string; }' and 'HandlerReturnType' are incompatible.
//    The types of 'x' are incompatible between these types.
//      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```

Instead, I would like typescript to be a bit more specific about the error. In order to do that, I have two choices:

1. Either move the type closer to the scope:

```js
const handler = ({ a }: HandlerParams): HandlerReturnType => {
  return { x: "string" }
}

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
// input.tsx(1, 28): The expected type comes from property 'x' which is declared here on type 'HandlerReturnType'
```

2. Return the value in the same scope:

```js
const handler: Handler = ({ a }) => ({ x: "string" })
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
// input.tsx(1, 28): The expected type comes from property 'x' which is declared here on type 'HandlerReturnType'
```

Option 1 is too "verbose" in more complex structures, and Option 2 will make the code unreadable in complex logic.

Now, I understand the reason why i'm getting a "simplified" or a "complex" error, but I'm looking for a way to get the "simplfiieerror without compromising what I've mentioned above.

Comment: there seems to be an open feature request to use the shorthand error message on arrow functions with type errors: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49375

Comment: and another related request here, pretty similar to what you're talking about (it seems like shorthand errors are just generally not implemented for arrow functions?) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42161

Comment: @worc Thanks for taking your time looking into it. Seems like I'll have to stick with my first option.